# Google PlayResolver in Unity Automated Build

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, build

I have a repository containing my game, and inside it is firebase messaging and analytics SDK imported from the .unitypackage BUT i don’t have the android dependencies installed (the ones that Play Resolver download i guess using gradle).

So in a normal flow using the unity editor, play resolver will download the needed dependencies and put them inside my project. If i build everything works.

The problem is in the automated build where we call unity via command line executing a custom build pipeline. In this scenario the android dependencies are not downloaded (play resolver download is not triggered) so unity create the apk without those dependencies, and when i try to open the app it crashes because it doesn’t have some AndroidManifest code inside.

EDIT

In my pipeline i have a preprocess script that run this code

```
PlayServicesResolver.Resolve(continuePipeline, true, b => Debug.Log("Success: " + b));
```

if i run my pipeline from a MenuItem in unity editor the build succeed downloading the dependencies and the creating the apk but when i run the command with unity closed, the process will open Unity try to resolve the dependencies but it kill the batchmode and stop the pipeline.

```
DependOn - group: com.google.firebase artifact: firebase-messaging-unity version: 4.3.0 packageIds:  repositories: Assets/Firebase/m2repository
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Google.Logger:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:LogDelegate(String, LogLevel)
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport:Log(String, LogLevel, Boolean)
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport:DependOn(String, String, String, String[], String[], String)
GooglePlayServices.<Read>c__AnonStoreyC:<>m__E(XmlTextReader, String, Boolean, String, List`1)
Google.XmlUtilities:ParseXmlTextFileElements(String, Logger, ParseElement)
GooglePlayServices.AndroidXmlDependencies:Read(String, Logger)
GooglePlayServices.XmlDependencies:ReadAll(Logger)
GooglePlayServices.AndroidXmlDependencies:ReadAll(Logger)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:ResolveUnsafe(Action`1, Boolean)
GooglePlayServices.<Resolve>c__AnonStorey11:<>m__19()
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:ExecuteNextResolveJob()
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Resolve(Action, Boolean, Action`1)
BuilderPreProccess:Run(BuildType, BuildTarget, Action) (at Assets/Editor/BuilderPreProccess.cs:10)
Etermax.CI.Builder:BuildPreProccess(BuildTarget, BuildType, Action) (at Assets/Standard Assets/node_modules/@etermax/etermax-ci/Assets/Package/Editor/Builder.cs:158)
Etermax.CI.Builder:RunPreProccess(BuildType, BuildTarget, Action) (at Assets/Standard Assets/node_modules/@etermax/etermax-ci/Assets/Package/Editor/Builder.cs:47)
Etermax.CI.ProjectBuilders:CIBuildQA() (at Assets/Standard Assets/node_modules/@etermax/etermax-ci/Assets/Package/Editor/ProjectBuilders.cs:69)

(Filename: Assets/Editor/BuilderPreProccess.cs Line: 10)

Refresh: detecting if any assets need to be imported or removed ... Refresh: elapses 0.224102 seconds (Nothing changed)
Resolving...
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Google.Logger:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:ResolveUnsafe(Action`1, Boolean)
GooglePlayServices.<Resolve>c__AnonStorey11:<>m__19()
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:ExecuteNextResolveJob()
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Resolve(Action, Boolean, Action`1)
BuilderPreProccess:Run(BuildType, BuildTarget, Action) (at Assets/Editor/BuilderPreProccess.cs:10)
Etermax.CI.Builder:BuildPreProccess(BuildTarget, BuildType, Action) (at Assets/Standard Assets/node_modules/@etermax/etermax-ci/Assets/Package/Editor/Builder.cs:158)
Etermax.CI.Builder:RunPreProccess(BuildType, BuildTarget, Action) (at Assets/Standard Assets/node_modules/@etermax/etermax-ci/Assets/Package/Editor/Builder.cs:47)
Etermax.CI.ProjectBuilders:CIBuildQA() (at Assets/Standard Assets/node_modules/@etermax/etermax-ci/Assets/Package/Editor/ProjectBuilders.cs:69)

(Filename: Assets/Editor/BuilderPreProccess.cs Line: 10)

Query Android SDK packages

/Users/martin/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --list --verbose

UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Google.Logger:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.SdkManagerUtil:QueryPackages(String, String, Action`1)
GooglePlayServices.SdkManager:QueryPackages(Action`1)
GooglePlayServices.<DoResolution>c__AnonStorey10:<>m__16(IAndroidSdkManager)
GooglePlayServices.AndroidSdkManager:Create(String, Action`1)
GooglePlayServices.GradlePreBuildResolver:DoResolution(PlayServicesSupport, String, Action)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:ResolveUnsafe(Action`1, Boolean)
GooglePlayServices.<Resolve>c__AnonStorey11:<>m__19()
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:ExecuteNextResolveJob()
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Resolve(Action, Boolean, Action`1)
BuilderPreProccess:Run(BuildType, BuildTarget, Action) (at Assets/Editor/BuilderPreProccess.cs:10)
Etermax.CI.Builder:BuildPreProccess(BuildTarget, BuildType, Action) (at Assets/Standard Assets/node_modules/@etermax/etermax-ci/Assets/Package/Editor/Builder.cs:158)
Etermax.CI.Builder:RunPreProccess(BuildType, BuildTarget, Action) (at Assets/Standard Assets/node_modules/@etermax/etermax-ci/Assets/Package/Editor/Builder.cs:47)
Etermax.CI.ProjectBuilders:CIBuildQA() (at Assets/Standard Assets/node_modules/@etermax/etermax-ci/Assets/Package/Editor/ProjectBuilders.cs:69)

(Filename: Assets/Editor/BuilderPreProccess.cs Line: 10)

Executing command: /Users/martin/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --list --verbose
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Google.Logger:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.CommandLineDialog:RunAsync(String, String, CompletionHandler, String, Dictionary`2, IOHandler, Int32)
GooglePlayServices.SdkManagerUtil:QueryPackages(String, String, Action`1)
GooglePlayServices.SdkManager:QueryPackages(Action`1)
GooglePlayServices.<DoResolution>c__AnonStorey10:<>m__16(IAndroidSdkManager)
GooglePlayServices.AndroidSdkManager:Create(String, Action`1)
GooglePlayServices.GradlePreBuildResolver:DoResolution(PlayServicesSupport, String, Action)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:ResolveUnsafe(Action`1, Boolean)
GooglePlayServices.<Resolve>c__AnonStorey11:<>m__19()
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:ExecuteNextResolveJob()
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Resolve(Action, Boolean, Action`1)
BuilderPreProccess:Run(BuildType, BuildTarget, Action) (at Assets/Editor/BuilderPreProccess.cs:10)
Etermax.CI.Builder:BuildPreProccess(BuildTarget, BuildType, Action) (at Assets/Standard Assets/node_modules/@etermax/etermax-ci/Assets/Package/Editor/Builder.cs:158)
Etermax.CI.Builder:RunPreProccess(BuildType, BuildTarget, Action) (at Assets/Standard Assets/node_modules/@etermax/etermax-ci/Assets/Package/Editor/Builder.cs:47)
Etermax.CI.ProjectBuilders:CIBuildQA() (at Assets/Standard Assets/node_modules/@etermax/etermax-ci/Assets/Package/Editor/ProjectBuilders.cs:69)

(Filename: Assets/Editor/BuilderPreProccess.cs Line: 10)

Batchmode quit successfully invoked - shutting down!
```